# How to remove a list object using angularJS

Tags: javascript, java, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hi I have a Angular data as follows,

```
{"category":"B","check_histories":[{"date_created":"2015-10-07T10:35:38","field_name":"category","new_value":"B","old_value":null,"resource_uri":"","type":1,"username":"e1007476"},{"date_created":"2015-10-07T10:35:39","field_name":"check_name","new_value":"222","old_value":null,"resource_uri":"","type":1,"username":"e1007476"},{"date_created":"2015-10-07T10:37:25","field_name":"check_name","new_value":"22233","old_value":"222","resource_uri":"","type":0,"username":"e1007476"}],"check_name":"22233","date_created":"2015-10-07T10:35:38","date_modified":"2015-10-07T10:37:25","id":134,"is_valid":true,"resource_uri":""}
```

How to remove all the data EXCEPT `check_historie`s from the data, when I click a remove button. I have tried

```
$scope.clear = function(index) {
        $scope.final_data.checks.splice(index, 1);
    };
```

But it deleted the entire data, instead of the desired part. Am quite new to AngualrJS. Please help me on it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you only want to keep check_histories property ?

Comment: Yes, thats right Anik

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript "delete" as following:

```
delete $scope.final_data.checks.category;
// or,
delete $scope.final_data.checks['category'];
// or,
var prop = "category";
delete $scope.final_data.checks[prop];
```

In your case you have to loop through your object property and delete them:

```
angular.forEach($scope.final_data, function(value, key) {
   if(key !== 'check_histories') {
      delete $scope.final_data[key];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Underscore way:

```
$scope.final_data.checks = _.pick($scope.final_data.checks, 'check_histories');
```